# Creating database via flask in postgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I m trying a tutorial, to make a database connection with flask, and postgreSQL database using json.

This is the code lines in models.py

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON

class Result(db.Model):
    _tablename_= 'results'

    id =db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String())
    result_all = db.Column(JSON)
    result_no_stop_words = db.Column(JSON)

    def __init__(self, url, result_all, result_no_stop_words):
        self.url = url
        self.result_all = result_all
        self.result_no_stop_words = result_no_stop_words

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)
```

Code in config.py

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'this-really-needs-to-be-changed'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['postgresql://postgresql:bat123@localhost/DatabaseFirst']

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False

class StagingConfig(Config):
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    DEBUG = True

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    DEBUG = True

class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
```

Code in manage.py

```
import os
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

from app import app, db

app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

code in app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from models import Result

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route('/<name>')
def hello_name(name):
    return "Hello {}!".format(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I want to know before running this code lines should the database be created in postgreSQL, alone with the table, and columns, 

Or these code lines creating the table, and columns in postgreSQL

```
class Result(db.Model):
    _tablename_= 'results'

    id =db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String())
    result_all = db.Column(JSON)
    result_no_stop_words = db.Column(JSON)
```

Basically i want to know the function or purpose served by the above set of code lines.(5 code lines)

Comment: If these two things have not been explained in the tutorial, you might want to try an other one.

Answer (score 1):

`manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)` this piece adds a command called `db` so that you can run `flask db` which will create the tables and columns.

Note: inorder to use this command first you need to define `FLASK_APP` in the environment variables.

Eg:

```
export FLASK_APP=app.py
flask db
```

Also the model

```
class Result(db.Model): _tablename_= 'results' id =db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) url = db.Column(db.String()) result_all = db.Column(JSON) result_no_stop_words = db.Column(JSON)
```

This defines the class representation of the table. It won't create table in database, it's just the representation. The `MigrationCommand` is responsible for the creation of tables in database.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Result(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'results'

    id =db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

**`class Result(db.Model)`**:

This code line is creating a class instance of `Result` in front end of Flask application and to pass those values to the Database postgreSQL or whatever respective database you will be using.

**`__tablename__ = 'results'`**:

Here we are creating a table called results in the database in my case `DatabaseFirst`

**`id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)`**:

Here we are creating a column called `id`, in our table called `results`, which can hold only data of integer type and `id` column is assigned the primary key of the results table.

Here by the 3 code lines I mentioned above, the database tables and columns are created via the Flask application, and we can see the respective results on postgreSQL database.